# About homogenous completely irreducible module

Tags: abstract-algebra, modules, representation-theory, characters

I'm stuck on something, I'd appreciate it if you could help :)

Let $A$ be a $F$-algebra, $V$ be a completely reducible $A$-module and $M$ is an irreducible $A$- module. Now let's consider $M(V)$, which is the homogenous part of $V$. ( Recall: $M(V)$: sum of submodules of $V$ isomorphic to the irreducible $M$.) My question is the following :

How can we prove that
"If $U$ is a submodule of $V$, then $M(U) = U \cap M(V)$"

My attempt : Actually, the left side is obvious because any submodule of $U$ which isomorphic to $M$ is also a submodule of $V$ isomorphic to M, and so $ M(U) \subset M(V)$. How can we get the other side ?

Comment: You need to know that every submodule of $M(V)$ is again a sum of submodules isomorphic to $M$. Then $U\cap M(V)$ is a sum of submodules of $U$ which are isomorphic to $M$, so is contained in $M(U)$.

Comment: I understood the argument you used, however I wonder the following : Can we say immediately that submodule of a module( that is a direct sum) is again sum of submodules ?I think,  any subspace of a direct sum is not necessarily a direct sum of subspaces?

Comment: We can do this here because $M$ is irreducible. It is then true that $M(V)$ is isomorphic to a direct sum of copies of $M$, and every submodule is a direct summand. Basically, $\mathrm{End}(M)$ is a division ring, by Schur’s Lemma, and $M(V)$ is a module over the endomorphism ring. The theory is then completely analogous to vector spaces over a field.

Comment: See here: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Semisimple_module